# Django Error: HttpResponse Invalid Syntax

Tags: django, syntax-error, httpresponse

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    reutrn HttpResponse("<h1>This is a test</h1>")
```

No matter what I do this syntax error always shows up!

```
File "C:\Users\#24\Python Projects\Test\Packages\views.py", line 6
reutrn HttpResponse("<h1>This is a test</h1>")
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've looked pretty hard to see if anyone else has had this problem but no dice. 
This is my first time trying out django

Comment: there is a typo within `return`, it should be `return HttpResponse("<h1>This is a test</h1>")` instead of `reutrn HttpResponse("<h1>This is a test</h1>")`

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was gonna be something simple!

Answer (score 2):

There is a spelling mistake in that line, You should type **return** instead of **reutrn**

```
    reutrn HttpResponse("<h1>This is a test</h1>")
```